# Upload a Profile Image in PHP & MySQL: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote the code thrice before coming here. Each time I got the same problem: The profile image does not change from the default placeholder to the new uploaded image. Here is the index.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "imgupload");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>
<?php
    $sql_user = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_user);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $id = $row['id']; //gets the id of the user just selected from the database
            $sql_img = "SELECT * FROM profileimg WHERE userid='$id'"; //check if we actually have a profile image uploaded from this user
            $resultImg = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_img); //check what the status is of this user in the image table
            while ($rowImg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImg)) {
                echo "<div class='user-container'>"; //check image status: uploaded or not uploaded
                    if ($rowImg['status'] == 0) {
                        echo "<img src='uploads/profile".$id.".jpg'>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<img src='uploads/profiledefault.jpg'>";
                    }
                    echo "<p>".$row['username']."</p>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "There are no users yet!";
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        if ($_SESSION['id'] == 1) {
            echo "You are logged in as user #1";
        }
        echo "<form action='upload.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type='file' name='file'>
            <button type='submit' name='submit'>UPLOAD</button>
        </form>";
    } else {
        echo "You are not logged in!";
        echo "<form action='signup.php' method='POST'>
            <input type='text' name='first' placeholder='First name'>
            <input type='text' name='last' placeholder='Last name'>
            <input type='text' name='uid' placeholder='Username'>
            <input type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'>
            <button type='submit' name='submitSignup'>Signup</button>
        </form>";
    }
?>
<p>Login as Admin</p><form action="login.php" method="POST"><button type="submit" name="submitLogin">Login</button></form><p>Logout</p>
<form action="logout.php" method="POST"><button type="submit" name="submitLogout">Logout</button></form></body></html>
```

And here is the upload.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "imgupload");
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $file['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $file['size'];
    $fileError = $file['error'];
    $fileType = $file['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName); //returns an array of data
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt)); //returns the last item in the array then lowercases it

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
                $fileNameNew = "profile".$id.".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                $sql = "UPDATE profileimg SET status=0 WHERE userid='$id';";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");
            } else {
                echo "Your file is too big!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "There was an error uploading your file!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }
}
```

I doubt there's anything wrong in the signup.php file. Why won't the profile image change when I upload?

Comment: Is it the browser cache that's getting in the way?

Comment: Do you get some kind of error or does any of your echoes get printed out? Some extra information would be nice.

Comment: @Vallas I don't any error messages on the webpage, neither are there any errors in the xampp/apache error-log file. The image gets transferred to the uploads folder successfully. Only the profiledefault image doesn't change on the webpage...

Comment: @DavidBrossard I clear the cache regularly, no issues there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you set $_SESSION ["id"] . I think $ _SESSION ["id"] duplicate and

```
$fileNameNew = "profile".$id.".".$fileActualExt;
```

$fileNameNew can be as "profile1.jpg", if profile1.jpg already exists then you cannot add file profile1.jpg to upload folder

Comment: The images are named differently before they are uploaded. After they are uploaded the name gets changed to "profile" plus the profile-id in the mysql database. As for the session, the session is set in the login.php file like so: if(isset($_POST['submitLogin'])) {
 $_SESSION['id'] = 1;
 header("Location: index.php");
}

Comment: one user can create multiple image, you should have a encryption name , maybe md5 () ( $fileNameNew ="profile". md5($file['name']).".".$fileActualExt;). And you save name file in database, inner join User table

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. However the issue at hand is to do with the image not changing at all. I've played around with different unique file names and those work fine:)